# Web3 Contract (React) - SafeERC20 Low Level Call failed with ERC20 Token (USDT)

Tags: web3js, erc-20

I am working since 8 days on a problem with my smart contract and / or with my Web3 App.

If I try to use the contract with ETH it works well in the moment I try to use it with an ERC20 token (USDT) it does not work and a SafeERC20 Low level failure shows up.
The approve works fine, the error appears at the stage of buying.

```
const { request } = await presaleContract.simulate.buyToken(
        [token.address || zeroAddress, amount],
        {
          value: token.address ? 0n : amount,
        }
      );
```

I have already added the ERC20 token to my contract
[image]

Here is the buyToken function of my smart contract:

```
function buyToken(
        address _token,
        uint256 _amount
    ) external payable saleEnabled {
        uint256 saleTokenAmt = _token != address(0)
        ? getTokenAmount(_token, _amount)
        : getTokenAmount(address(0), msg.value);
        require(
            (totalTokensSold + saleTokenAmt) < totalTokensforSale,
            "Presale: Not enough tokens to be sale"
        );

        if (_token != address(0)) {
            require(_amount > 0);
            IERC20(_token).safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, owner(), _amount);
        } else {
            payable(owner()).transfer(msg.value);
        }

        totalTokensSold += saleTokenAmt;
        BuyerTokenDetails storage buyerDetails = buyersDetails[msg.sender];
        if (!buyerDetails.exists) {
            buyers.push(msg.sender);
            buyerDetails.exists = true;
        } else if (buyerDetails.amount > 0) {
            buyerDetails.reward += getBuyerReward(msg.sender);
        }
        buyerDetails.amount += saleTokenAmt;
        buyerDetails.lastCalculatedTime = block.timestamp;
    }
```

Here is the web3 part:

```
const buyToken = async (value: string | number, token: Token) => {
    let success = false;
    let hash;

    if (!walletClient || !address) return { success, txHash: hash };

    setLoading(true);

    try {
      const amount = parseUnits(`${value}`, token.decimals);
      console.log(amount);
      console.log(token.decimals);
      if (token.address) {
        await checkAllowance(
          token,
          address,
          config.presaleContract[chain.id],
          amount
        );
      }
      
      const { request } = await presaleContract.simulate.buyToken(
        [token.address || zeroAddress, amount],
        {
          value: token.address ? 0n : amount,
        }
      );
      
      hash = await walletClient.writeContract(request);

      await publicClient.waitForTransactionReceipt({ hash });

       const purchased_amount = await presaleContract.read.getTokenAmount([
         token.address || zeroAddress,
         amount,
       ]);

       storeTransaction({
         wallet_address: address,
         purchased_amount: +format(purchased_amount),
         paid_amount: value,
         transaction_hash: hash,
         paid_with: token.symbol,
         chain: chain.id,
       });

       storeReferralTransaction({
         purchased_amount: +format(purchased_amount),
         paid: value,
         transaction_hash: hash,
         payable_token: token.symbol,
         chain: chain.id,
       });

      fetchTokenBalances();
      fetchLockedBalance();
      fetchTotalTokensSold();

      toast.success(
        `You have successfully purchased $${
          config.saleToken[chain.id].symbol
        } Tokens. Thank you!`
      );

      success = true;
    } catch (error: any) {
      toast.error(
        error?.walk?.()?.shortMessage ||
          error?.walk?.()?.message ||
          error?.message ||
          "Signing failed, please try again!"
      );
    }

    setLoading(false);

    return { success, txHash: hash };
  };
```

Would be nice if someone can assist me.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT 1 :
Full Code:

```
import config, { presaleStartTime } from "../config";
import { RootState } from "../store";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import {
  setSaleStatus,
  setTokenPrice,
  setTotalTokensforSale,
  setTotalTokensSold,
} from "../store/presale";
import { useMemo, useState } from "react";
import {
  erc20ABI,
  useAccount,
  useNetwork,
  usePublicClient,
  useWalletClient,
} from "wagmi";
import { setBalance } from "../store/wallet";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

import {
  createPublicClient,
  formatUnits,
  getContract,
  http,
  parseUnits,
  zeroAddress,
} from "viem";
import { presaleAbi } from "../contracts/presaleABI";
import { storeReferralTransaction, storeTransaction } from "../utils/apis";
import dayjs from "dayjs";

const publicClient = createPublicClient({
  chain: config.chains[0],
  transport: http(),
  batch: { multicall: true },
});

const useWeb3Functions = () => {
  const network = useNetwork();
  const chain = useMemo(() => {
    return network.chain && !network.chain.unsupported
      ? network.chain
      : config.chains[0];
  }, [network.chain]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const tokens = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.presale.tokens);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const provider = usePublicClient();
  const { data: walletClient } = useWalletClient();
  const { address } = useAccount();

  const presaleContract = useMemo(
    () =>
      getContract({
        address: config.presaleContract[chain.id],
        abi: presaleAbi,
        walletClient: walletClient || undefined,
        publicClient,
      }),
    [walletClient, chain.id]
  );

  const fetchIntialData = async () => {
    setLoading(true);

    const [saleStatus] = await Promise.all([
      presaleContract.read.saleStatus(),
      fetchTotalTokensSold(),
      fetchTokenPrices(),
    ]);

    dispatch(setSaleStatus(saleStatus));

    setLoading(false);
  };

  const fetchTotalTokensSold = async () => {
    let extraAmount = 0;
    let incrase = 0;

    const totalTokensSold = await presaleContract.read.totalTokensSold();

    try {
      const resposne = await fetch("/settings.json");
      const settings = await resposne.json();
      extraAmount = settings?.x;
      incrase = settings?.y;
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-empty
    } catch (e) {}

    const amount = +format(totalTokensSold) || 0;
    const m = dayjs().diff(dayjs.unix(presaleStartTime), "minute");

    const ext = amount + incrase * Math.floor(m / 10);
    let total = (amount < ext ? ext : amount) + extraAmount;
    total = total > config.stage.total ? config.stage.total : total;
    dispatch(setTotalTokensSold(total));
  };

  const fetchLockedBalance = async () => {
    if (!address) return;

    const { symbol, decimals } = config.saleToken[chain.id];
    const [buyersDetails, remainingRewrards] = await Promise.all([
      presaleContract.read.buyersDetails([address]),
      presaleContract.read.getBuyerReward([address]),
    ]);

    const amount = buyersDetails[0] + buyersDetails[3] + remainingRewrards;
    const balance = +formatUnits(amount, decimals);

    dispatch(setBalance({ symbol: symbol, balance }));
  };

  const fetchTokenBalances = async () => {
    if (!address) return;

    const balancses = await Promise.all(
      tokens[chain.id].map((token) => {
        if (token.address) {
          return publicClient.readContract({
            address: token.address,
            abi: erc20ABI,
            functionName: "balanceOf",
            args: [address],
          });
        } else {
          return provider.getBalance({ address });
        }
      })
    );

    tokens[chain.id].forEach((token, index) => {
      dispatch(
        setBalance({
          symbol: token.symbol,
          balance: +formatUnits(balancses[index], token.decimals),
        })
      );
    });
  };

  const fetchTokenPrices = async () => {
    const pricses = await Promise.all(
      tokens[chain.id].map((token) => {
        if (token.address) {
          return presaleContract.read.tokenPrices([token.address]);
        } else {
          return presaleContract.read.rate();
        }
      })
    );

    tokens[chain.id].forEach((token, index) => {
      dispatch(
        setTokenPrice({
          symbol: token.symbol,
          price: +formatUnits(pricses[index], token.decimals),
        })
      );
    });
  };

  const checkAllowance = async (
    token: Token,
    owner: Address,
    spender: Address,
    amount: bigint
  ) => {
    if (!token.address || !walletClient) return;

    const tokenContract = getContract({
      address: token.address,
      abi: erc20ABI,
      walletClient,
      publicClient,
    });
    const allowance = await tokenContract.read.allowance([owner, spender]);

    if (allowance < amount) {
      const hash = await tokenContract.write.approve([
        spender,
        parseUnits("9999999999999999999999999999", token.decimals),
      ]);
      await publicClient.waitForTransactionReceipt({ hash });
      toast.success("Spend approved");
    }
  };

  const buyToken = async (value: string | number, token: Token) => {
    let success = false;
    let hash;

    if (!walletClient || !address) return { success, txHash: hash };

    setLoading(true);

    try {
      const amount = parseUnits(`${value}`, token.decimals);
      console.log(amount);
      console.log(token.decimals);
      if (token.address) {
        await checkAllowance(
          token,
          address,
          config.presaleContract[chain.id],
          amount
        );
      }
      
      const { request } = await presaleContract.simulate.buyToken(
        [token.address || zeroAddress, amount],
        {
          value: token.address ? 0n : amount,
        }
      );
      
      hash = await walletClient.writeContract(request);

      await publicClient.waitForTransactionReceipt({ hash });

       const purchased_amount = await presaleContract.read.getTokenAmount([
         token.address || zeroAddress,
         amount,
       ]);

       storeTransaction({
         wallet_address: address,
         purchased_amount: +format(purchased_amount),
         paid_amount: value,
         transaction_hash: hash,
         paid_with: token.symbol,
         chain: chain.id,
       });

       storeReferralTransaction({
         purchased_amount: +format(purchased_amount),
         paid: value,
         transaction_hash: hash,
         payable_token: token.symbol,
         chain: chain.id,
       });

      fetchTokenBalances();
      fetchLockedBalance();
      fetchTotalTokensSold();

      toast.success(
        `You have successfully purchased $${
          config.saleToken[chain.id].symbol
        } Tokens. Thank you!`
      );

      success = true;
    } catch (error: any) {
      toast.error(
        error?.walk?.()?.shortMessage ||
          error?.walk?.()?.message ||
          error?.message ||
          "Signing failed, please try again!"
      );
    }

    setLoading(false);

    return { success, txHash: hash };
  };

  const unlockingTokens = async () => {
    if (!walletClient) return;

    setLoading(true);

    try {
      const { request } = await presaleContract.simulate.unlockToken();
      const hash = await walletClient.writeContract(request);
      await publicClient.waitForTransactionReceipt({ hash });

      fetchLockedBalance();

      toast.success("Tokens unlocked successfully");
    } catch (error: any) {
      toast.error(
        error?.walk?.()?.shortMessage ||
          error?.walk?.()?.message ||
          error?.message ||
          "Signing failed, please try again!"
      );
    }

    setLoading(false);
  };

  const addTokenAsset = async (token: Token) => {
    if (!token.address || !walletClient) return;
    try {
      await walletClient.watchAsset({
        method: "wallet_watchAsset",
        params: {
          type: "ERC20",
          options: {
            address: token.address,
            symbol: token.symbol,
            decimals: token.decimals ?? 18,
            image: token.image.includes("http")
              ? token.image
              : `${window.location.origin}${token.image}`,
          },
        },
      } as any);
      toast.success("Token imported to metamask successfully");
    } catch (e) {
      toast.error("Token import failed");
    }
  };

  const parse = (value: string | number) =>
    parseUnits(`${value}`, config.saleToken[chain.id].decimals);

  const format = (value: bigint) =>
    formatUnits(value, config.saleToken[chain.id].decimals);

  return {
    loading,
    parse,
    format,
    buyToken,
    addTokenAsset,
    fetchIntialData,
    unlockingTokens,
    fetchLockedBalance,
    fetchTokenBalances,
  };
};

export default useWeb3Functions;
```

EDIT 2 - Complete Smart Contract

```
contract PresaleToken is Ownable {
    using SafeERC20 for IERC20;

    struct BuyerTokenDetails {
        uint256 amount;
        bool exists;
        bool isClaimed;
        uint256 reward;
        uint lastCalculatedTime;
    }

    uint256 public multiplier; // in bps 10000 = 100%
    uint256 public rate;
    address public saleToken;
    uint public saleTokenDec;
    uint256 public totalTokensforSale;
    bool public saleStatus;
    address[] public buyers;
    uint256 public totalTokensSold;

    mapping(address => bool) public payableTokens;
    mapping(address => BuyerTokenDetails) public buyersDetails;
    mapping(address => uint256) public tokenPrices;

    modifier saleEnabled() {
        require(saleStatus == true, "Presale: is not enabled");
        _;
    }
    modifier saleStoped() {
        require(saleStatus == false, "Presale: is not stopped");
        _;
    }

    constructor() {
        saleStatus = false;
    }

    function setParams(
        address _saleToken,
        uint256 _totalTokensforSale,
        uint256 _rate,
        uint _multiplier,
        bool _saleStatus
    ) external onlyOwner {
        require(_rate != 0);
        rate = _rate;
        saleToken = _saleToken;
        saleStatus = _saleStatus;
        saleTokenDec = IERC20Metadata(saleToken).decimals();
        totalTokensforSale = _totalTokensforSale;
        multiplier = _multiplier;
        IERC20(saleToken).safeTransferFrom(
            msg.sender,
            address(this),
            totalTokensforSale
        );
    }

    function updateRewards() internal {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < buyers.length; i++) {
            if (buyersDetails[buyers[i]].amount > 0) {
                buyersDetails[buyers[i]].reward = getBuyerReward(buyers[i]);
                buyersDetails[buyers[i]].lastCalculatedTime = block.timestamp;
            }
        }
    }

    function setMultiplier(uint256 _multiplier) public onlyOwner {
        updateRewards();
        multiplier = _multiplier;
    }

    function increaseTotalTokensforSale(
        uint256 _totalTokensforSale
    ) external onlyOwner {
        totalTokensforSale += _totalTokensforSale;
        IERC20(saleToken).safeTransferFrom(
            msg.sender,
            address(this),
            _totalTokensforSale
        );
    }

    function stopSale() external onlyOwner {
        saleStatus = false;
    }

    function resumeSale() external onlyOwner {
        saleStatus = true;
    }

    function addPayableTokens(
        address[] memory _tokens,
        uint256[] memory _prices
    ) external onlyOwner {
        require(
            _tokens.length == _prices.length,
            "Presale: tokens & prices arrays length mismatch"
        );
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _tokens.length; i++) {
            require(_prices[i] != 0);
            payableTokens[_tokens[i]] = true;
            tokenPrices[_tokens[i]] = _prices[i];
        }
    }

    function payableTokenStatus(
        address _token,
        bool _status
    ) external onlyOwner {
        require(payableTokens[_token] != _status);
        payableTokens[_token] = _status;
    }

    function updateTokenRate(
        address[] memory _tokens,
        uint256[] memory _prices,
        uint256 _rate
    ) external onlyOwner {
        require(
            _tokens.length == _prices.length,
            "Presale: tokens & prices arrays length mismatch"
        );
        if (_rate != 0) {
            rate = _rate;
        }
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _tokens.length; i += 1) {
            require(payableTokens[_tokens[i]] == true);
            require(_prices[i] != 0);
            tokenPrices[_tokens[i]] = _prices[i];
        }
    }

    function getTokenAmount(
        address token,
        uint256 amount
    ) public view returns (uint256) {
        uint256 amtOut;
        if (token != address(0)) {
            require(payableTokens[token] == true, "Presale: Token not allowed");
            uint256 price = tokenPrices[token];
            amtOut = (amount * (10 ** saleTokenDec)) / (price);
        } else {
            amtOut = (amount * (10 ** saleTokenDec)) / (rate);
        }
        return amtOut;
    }

    function buyToken(
        address _token,
        uint256 _amount
    ) external payable saleEnabled {
        uint256 saleTokenAmt = _token != address(0)
        ? getTokenAmount(_token, _amount)
        : getTokenAmount(address(0), msg.value);
        require(
            (totalTokensSold + saleTokenAmt) < totalTokensforSale,
            "Presale: Not enough tokens to be sale"
        );

        if (_token != address(0)) {
            require(_amount > 0);
            IERC20(_token).safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, owner(), _amount);
        } else {
            payable(owner()).transfer(msg.value);
        }

        totalTokensSold += saleTokenAmt;
        BuyerTokenDetails storage buyerDetails = buyersDetails[msg.sender];
        if (!buyerDetails.exists) {
            buyers.push(msg.sender);
            buyerDetails.exists = true;
        } else if (buyerDetails.amount > 0) {
            buyerDetails.reward += getBuyerReward(msg.sender);
        }
        buyerDetails.amount += saleTokenAmt;
        buyerDetails.lastCalculatedTime = block.timestamp;
    }

    function getBuyerReward(address buyer) public view returns (uint256) {
        if (buyersDetails[buyer].amount == 0) return 0;

        uint daysPassed = (block.timestamp -
        buyersDetails[buyer].lastCalculatedTime) / 86400;

        uint256 reward = (buyersDetails[buyer].amount *
        multiplier *
        daysPassed) / 10000;

        return reward;
    }

    function unlockTokenFor(address buyer) internal {
        if (buyersDetails[buyer].amount > 0) {
            uint256 tokensforWithdraw = buyersDetails[buyer].amount +
            buyersDetails[buyer].reward +
            getBuyerReward(buyer);
            buyersDetails[buyer].amount = 0;
            buyersDetails[buyer].reward = 0;
            IERC20(saleToken).safeTransfer(buyer, tokensforWithdraw);
        }
    }

    function unlockToken() external saleStoped {
        require(
            buyersDetails[msg.sender].amount > 0,
            "Presale: No tokens to claim"
        );
        unlockTokenFor(msg.sender);
    }

    // Method to unlock all the tokens
    function unlockAllTokens() external onlyOwner saleStoped {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < buyers.length; i++) {
            unlockTokenFor(buyers[i]);
        }
    }

    function withdrawAllSaleTokens() external onlyOwner saleStoped {
        uint256 amt = IERC20(saleToken).balanceOf(address(this));
        IERC20(saleToken).transfer(msg.sender, amt);
        totalTokensforSale = 0;
    }

    function withdraw(address token, uint256 amt) public onlyOwner {
        IERC20(token).safeTransfer(msg.sender, amt);
    }

    function withdrawAll(address token) public onlyOwner {
        uint256 amt = IERC20(token).balanceOf(address(this));
        withdraw(token, amt);
    }

    function withdrawCurrency(uint256 amt) public onlyOwner {
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(amt);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the full code, including the `checkAllowance` function? Also, what functions do you use to grant the allowance for the contract to expend the `msg.sender`'s tokens?

Comment: Hi Mila, thank you for your response. I have edited my Question with the full code.

Comment: I had a look. Have you checked whether the connected account has sufficient ERC20 funds?

Comment: Mila, thank you for your time. The account has way enough ERC20 tokens and also ETH on the account to cover the fee.

Comment: the problem still exist and I dev not know why ^^

Comment: That is quite a strange case: your code looks OK, but maybe the problem is something inside the logic. Oh, and I just thought about one more thing that could be the culprit... It's better to double-check to confirm that the sender account is not **blacklisted**: https://etherscan.io/address/0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7#readContract#F18

Comment: Anyways, that is something inside the USDT calls for sure

Comment: I could play around with it more if you can provide a CodeSandbox link for me, because I don't have all the project configs that you have.

Comment: Or, *if you're sending this transaction on mainnet or a public testnet*, you can send me a `txHash`, and I'll take a look

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/inspiring-ride-gmj64s

Comment: I didn't run a test because I don't have USDT on Goerli, but I noticed some issues with the CodeSandbox minimal viable reproducement example. It looks like package.json is also missing in the CodeSadnbox workspace that you shared. Can you try the same thing with the updated code: https://github.com/milaabl/xw-react-typescript-app?

Comment: Please also make sure to take a closer look at these *fixed* lines: https://github.com/milaabl/xw-react-typescript-app/blob/8dc18fb00820239e96d84513cf9a5fb0c4c8b5e1/src/hooks/useWeb3Functions.ts#L185

Comment: I have updated the package.json in the codeSandbox. I think I have not overwrite the original one in the moment I have uploaded the files

Comment: After I have edited the line 57 ( client: walletClient) I got this error:
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'client' does not exist in type 'GetContractParameters<Transport, Chain | undefined, Account | undefined, readonly [{ readonly inputs: readonly []; readonly stateMutability: "nonpayable"; readonly type: "constructor"; }, ... 31 more ..., { ...; }], { ...; } | undefined, { ...; } | undefined, `0x${string}`>'.ts(2353)

Comment: Mila, if you want you can contact me via mail - liopleurodon87@gmail.com
I have used your updated source but now there are other errors ;-) I think it makes sense to discuss if you are available for a freelance offer.

Comment: I have tried your  well updated code, but if it starts for the first time it does not get the data from the contract.

Comment: I'll try to fork Ethereum with a local Ganache client, let me test it myself then... I'm mainly doing this for gaining reputation and solving curious problems here on SE, but if I find a solution, you can thank me by sending ETH/USDT to this address if you want (0x0EBE38D7106D595e8Ee5a9a145D277A859F70046).

Comment: I will do it for sure :-) You helped me a lot until now and I think we can figure out the rest also :-)

Comment: please take a look at the updated code in the repo :) (https://github.com/milaabl/xw-react-typescript-app)

Comment: I sent you an email.

Answer (score 0):

While I have not reproduced it with your contract specifically, I believe editing these lines could be helpful, and let's see whether it fixes the problem:

```js
const tokenContract = getContract({
      address: token.address,
      abi: erc20ABI,
      client: walletClient
    });
```

*(Here:)*

[image: erc20-viem-low-level-call-failed]

There're no `walletClient` or `publicClient` arguments that the `viem.getContract(...)` method accepts.

---

I'm not sure if that helps, but please check that out and let me know. :)

Comment: Thank you again, Mila for your help.
Now I get this error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'allowance')